# how to reinstall ubuntu software updater

Tags: 20.04, update-manager

I accidentally xkill-ed my ubuntu software&update app. how can i reinstall it

Answer (score 0):

xkill does not uninstall the software. It should not need to be reinstalled.

You have some alternatives:

1. Simply logout and login. That should restore Software Updater.
2. Use a terminal instead: Run `update-manager` to launch Software Updater

If you meant to say that the software-update icon on the top bar is now missing, logout/login or run 'update-notifier'